# Want to change URL of website with subdomain

Tags: wordpress, url

I have url like domain.com/store/storename but i want to rewrite as storename.domain.com as a subdomain URL.

How can I do this? Can anyone help me out?

I am using WordPress. I want to do this via .htaccess file.

Comment: you cannot do this only with htaccess ... your  subdomain need to be registred first and make it's folder the wordpress site, then update the url in the setting of your site

Comment: If you don't know to do this, you should use a plugin like Duplicator to handle the internal changes for you.

Comment: @TemaniAfif If i registered subdomain and assign folder then what change i have to made in .htaccess file

Comment: you don't have to touch the htaccess, you need to change the setting in the wordpress site, and update the base url

Answer (score -1):

```
AS I understand it you want to make it work like following :

    a.xyz.com 
    b.xyz.com
    c.xyz.com

This is to be done on single wordpress installation which is done on www.xyz.com
You have separate sections running under a URL like :
    www.xyz.com/1/a
    www.xyz.com/1/b
    www.xyz.com/1/c

You want them to be openend with subdomains.

Thanks.
```

Comment: Yes , I want exactly like this